# stripe api: is it possible to expand invoice discounts from the events api?

Tags: stripe-payments

In the stripe API there is no endpoint to load discounts by Id, so typically when querying the `invoices` api you append `?expand[]=data.discounts` to the request and it populates the details of the discounts in the returned objects.  This is the only way I know of to get the discounts from the API.

In the `events` api you get back lots of different kinds of objects, but for the invoices I would like to also expand the discounts because I do not know how to get them otherwise.  I have tried appending the following expand paramaters to the events api and always get back an `invalid_request_error` from their api telling me that the field I request can not be expanded.

- `?expand[]=discounts`
- `?expand[]=object.discounts`
- `?expand[]=data.discounts`
- `?expand[]=data.object.discounts`
- `?expand[]=data.data.object.discounts`
- `?expand[]=data.data.discounts`

Is it possible to expand the discounts on invoices from the stripe events api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From synthrider on Stripe Developer Community Discord:

> hello!  No, events can't be expanded , you'd need to request this from the related API directly